# Select two ID from database

Tags: mysql

I have one question about select from tables from Mysql. 
I have two table, the first table is Project:
Project

```
ID name        student1   student2


1  delete       1            2
```

other table is student table:
student

```
studentID name


1          Tom


2          Nina
```

How to select which can produce the table like this?

```
Projectname student1  student1name student2 student2name
delete        1             Tom         2         Nani
```

Comment: what did you tried? Where you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

maybe something like ([sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e6171/1))

```
SELECT 
    p.ProjectName, s1.studentId student1, s1.Name student1name, s2.studentId student2, s2.Name student2name
FROM   
    Project p 
    INNER JOIN Student s1 ON p.student1 = s1.studentId
    INNER JOIN Student s2 ON p.student2 = s2.studentId
```

Comment: Thanks, but I have only two tables student and project.

Comment: this joins the student table to the project table twice and gets the final results, look at the sqlfiddle.